# Pause youtube video Through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I am having Youtube video url opened in object tag as

```
<object data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a18py61_F_w?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent" style="width:100%;height:100%;width: 380px; height: 214px; float: none; clear: both; margin: 2px auto;">  </object>
```

I want to stop video by using code javascript code or jquery code.

Note: I can't use iframe

Any Help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed id="playerid" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="playerid" style="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a18py61_F_w?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent" style="width:100%;height:100%;width: 380px; height: 214px; float: none; clear: both; margin: 2px auto;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">



<a href="#" onclick="var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid'); myPlayer.pauseVideo();">Pause</a>
```